# Not able to delete files using conda clean --all

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

> (you may need to reboot to free file handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\keyring.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\logged_subprocess.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\makedirs.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\metaclass.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\notebook_analyzer.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\pip_api.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\plugins.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\py2_compat.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\rename.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\simple_status.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\slugify.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\streaming_popen.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\toposort.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\windows_cmdline.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal\ziputils.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\internal_*init*_.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\test\test_conda_env.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\test\test_download_provider.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\test\test_redis_provider.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\test_*init*_.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\conda_env.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\download.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers\redis.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\providers_*init*_.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles) WARNING
> conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not
> remove or rename
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-project-0.10.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\anaconda_project\requirements_registry\requirements\test\test_conda_env.py.
> Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file
> handles)

Comment: Update your question with all information about your errors.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the command using a terminal with privileges

Comment: you should add this as a comment not answer

Comment: Thank you so much, helped me free up 11 gb of data.

Comment: Further all this issue started when i configured gitbash.

Comment: i get this error message, whenever i try to switch between my environments.      
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

Comment: Probably you need set conda in the path, try to reinstall again.

Comment: @deadshot why? Sounds like this was the answer

Comment: @pavan Please post a new question to ask about how to set up gitbash